# Making a image in a textview a fixed size - Android

Tags: java, android, image, textview

I am trying to assign an image to a TextView.  I pulled a .PNG from Google and now am trying to assign the width and height of the TextView to the size I want the image to be.  I want it to be a small square but it is turning out extremely wide and short rectangle.

Am I going about this all wrong?  Below is the code.

xml code

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q1Image"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

java code

```
q1Image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_x);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do-  get the text to go over the image, centered?  If so, you need to do it a bit differently

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width=wrap_content
  android:layout_height=wrap_content>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width=fill_parent
        android:layout_height=fill_parent
        android:gravity:"center" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width=wrap_content
        android:layout_height=wrap_content
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This will place an image view and a text view at the same spot, making the relative layout equal in size to the image and the text view equal in size to the layout.  Then it centers the text via gravity

Comment: I am not wanting to display any text, only an image.

Comment: Then why are you using a TextView instead of an ImageView?

Comment: I guess because I am a newbie to Android/mobile programming.  I will switch to ImageView and give it a go!

Comment: No problems.  General rule of thumb with views is that each one has a main purpose, and if you're trying to use it for something else there's probably a better tool out there.

Comment: The results is the same.  The image is a long flat rectangle even when I have the width and height as the same number of 10dp.

Comment: IS the image shaped like a long flat rectangle?  If so, that's expected.  Try a scaleType on the image of FILL_XY so that x and y are independently scaled.  If not, what are the dimensions of the image source?

Answer (score 0):

```
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {

        Log.i(" get drawable mathod ", "");
        Bitmap B = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.bone);
        BitmapDrawable BD = new BitmapDrawable(B);

        BD.setBounds(0, 0, B.getWidth(), B.getHeight());

        return BD;
    }
```

You can specify the height and width to get it adjusted based on your requireements

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation of [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

TextView have functions like :

[setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,int,int,int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)
[setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(int,int,int,int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)
and other functions that might help you.